# Can't figure how to retrieve data of a particular row from a ListView

Tags: android

I am developing an android application pertaining to sms. I have managed to display a listView of all the messages in my android emulator, but i can't figure out what code should i write in the onItemClickListener such that whenever i click any row of my listview i should get the data(here.. message body) associated with it in another screen. What ahould i do about this?

My code is given below:

```
public class mainmenu extends Activity 
{


       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) 
       {
          super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);



         super.onStart();
         {

          final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
          List<String> msgList = getSMS();
          ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, msgList); 
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
            {


                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });

       }
 }






       public List<String> getSMS()
       {

           List<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
           Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
          Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null,null,null);

          while (cur.moveToNext())
          {

              String address=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
              String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
                 sms.add("Number: " + address + " .Message: " + body); 
          }
          return sms;


       }

}
```

Please give me the code that i should write in the OnItemClickListener as per the specifications i mentioned above. It's a bit urgent.

Comment: Urgent for you is not urgent for a bunch of unpaid volunteers. It is rude to tell people who you are asking for help from to hurry up already...

Comment: i don't think likewise oded...!! i don't know how you define rudeness... but if i am developing an android project and it's submission is due in a week and if i come here requesting urgent help from the more experienced people makes me rude for you.. then so be it... Thank you..

Comment: Telling us to be quick about something _is_ rude.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the adapter there as such:

```
String itemAtClickedIntex = (String)adapter.getItem(position);
```

Hope this helps your urgent request :) please don't forget to accept as it encourages us to keep contributing.

Best

-serkan

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply... I am really sorry but I am a newbie to android programming.... and my project submission is due in a week... and i can't figure out this problem... a little more detailed description of the code would be very helpful.... and thanks again.. :-)

Comment: Hello Mehak, did you enter the code I've provided in your onItemClick method?  That should give you the data you're asking for.  If you have another question about it please specify it in your response and I'll try to help.